# Does Ubuntu have a log command I can use within my own perl scripts?

Tags: log

Am writing some perl scripts and would love to be able to **log** specific moments with a timestamp, pid, and other script specific data.

I was hoping Ubuntu had a command I could call from my scripts that would write to a log, while handling file locking (as multiple copies of the script could be running simultaneously.

Comment: `systemd-cat` & `journalctl`?